# Android invalidate(Rect) invalidates entire region

Tags: android, graphics, invalidation

I don't understand why invalidate(Rect) is invalidating the entire region.
The region is divided up into 5 sections and a line graph is being drawn in each one. Each section contains 100 points. As the data arrives for times tn to tn+100 I call invalidate(new Rect(left, top, right bottom)) where top is the top of the screen in height (but a lower numerical value than bottom). This invokes a call to the onDraw() method. The region from tn to tn+100 is drawn, but the previously drawn segment in region tn-100 to tn is erased. It continues that way forever. Each invalidate draws in only that region (since that is the only data I have) which IS correct, but all the previously drawn data is erased. So I get a marching segment!

In other words, I get identical behavior if I call invalidate() or invalidate(Rect).

I am assuming that the parameters of the Rect() are pixels and are getting the values based upon the height and width of the AlertDialog window in which this is being drawn.

The hope is eventually to reduce the region of 'Rect()' so I can simulate real time drawing and only invalidate time step t to t+1 instead of a region.

I must be doing something stupid.

I hope that the fact it is being done in an AlertDialog is not the issue.

This part is for trying to help 'android developer' help a noob like me get this right.
First the sequence of events:
1. Data is received via Bluetooth in a callback
2. If it is the right type of data, a BroadcastReceiver in the main activity (UI thread) is  signaled and from there a routine is called that sets the parameters of a WaveFormView extends View class and then ShowDialog(id) is called which calls the onCreateDialog(id) callback in the main activity.
3. Then I call invalidate().
4. The dialog pops up and then the graph is drawn.
5. All subsequent calls to ShowDialog(id) bypass the onCreateDialog(id)

That works but the entire region is always invalidated regardless of the parameters. There are also no user events here. From your example the best I could come up with is the following where I place invalidate in the onShow() instead of calling myself after the showDialog(id)

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Alert Dialog 'onCreateDialog' method has been called with id " + id);
    Builder bldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog alert = bldr.setView(waveForm).setNegativeButton("Dismiss " + id, 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                } 
            }).create();
    // I tried adding this and invalidating here worked only first pass
    alert.setOnShowListener(
                    new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
                        {
                            // call to invalidate
                            waveForm.drawArea();
                        }
                    });

    //alert.getWindow().setLayout(alert.getWindow().getAttributes().width, alert.getWindow().getAttributes().height / 2);
    alert.getWindow().setLayout(waveForm.getCurrentWidth(), waveForm.getCurrentHeight());

    return alert;
}
```

However the onShow() does not get called.

The method in the main activity that calls the showDialog is

```
private void displayRtsa(int[] rtsaReceived)
{
    // rtsaReceived[0] has the agentsink hash code
    int agent = rtsaReceived[0];
    // rtsaReceived[1] has the index of the RtsaData object updated
    int index = rtsaReceived[1];
    TreeMap<Integer, RtsaData[]> agentRtsa = BluetoothPanService.getAgentRtsaMap();
    RtsaData[] rtsaDataValues = agentRtsa.get(agent);

    int dialogId = 0;
    synchronized(dialogIds)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if(dialogIds.containsKey(agent + index) == false)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < dialogIds.size(); i++)
            {
                if(dialogIds.containsValue(i) == false)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            dialogIds.put(agent + index, i);
        }
        dialogId = dialogIds.get(agent + index);
    }
    final int id = dialogId;
    Log.d(TAG, "Dialog id being shown = " + dialogId);
    waveForm.setPeriod(rtsaDataValues[index].getPeriod());
    waveForm.setMaxMin(rtsaDataValues[index].getMinValue(), rtsaDataValues[index].getMaxValue());
    waveForm.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 200, 0));
    waveForm.setData(rtsaDataValues[index].getData());
    waveForm.setTitle(rtsaDataValues[index].getType());
    showDialog(id);
    // invalidate
    // waveForm.drawArea(); (try to do in onCreateDialog callback)
}
```

This is probably a completely wrong approach. Probably openGl is the only way.

By the way, thanks for putting up with me!

Answer (score 0):

i think it depends on what exactly you do the invalidation on . if the view you are calling the invalidation on didn't handle a rectangular invalidation , the default invalidation takes place.

in any case , if you wish to change the behavior , you can change it yourself. for the "onDraw" method , use the next code in order to fetch the invalidated rectangle :

```
public class InvalidateTestActivity extends Activity
{
    static class CustomView extends ImageView

    {

        public CustomView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            final Rect r = canvas.getClipBounds();
            Log.d("DEBUG", "rectangle of invalidation:" + r);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }

    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CustomView customView = new CustomView(this);
        customView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        customView.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
        customView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                v.invalidate(new Rect(0, 0, 49, 49));
            }
        });
        setContentView(customView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I called this method in the onDraw() routine and it turns out that the value returned is the same every time (the full area) and my settings are ignored. How can I change this behavior? Would that be some setting in the AlertDialog or will I need to make some type of customized dialog box?

Comment: not sure i get the whole picture. do you call invalidate on the exact same view that you've overridden the onDraw method ? if so , it should work. if not , it explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: I would think so. I have a class WaveFormView Extends View

Comment: (Sorry I was forced into this as I had paused 5 minutes) I would think so. I have a class WaveFormView Extends View.  One of the methods in the class is public void invalidateAreas(). In this method I invoke invalidate(Rect) and print out the rectangle coordinates. I call this method after setting up all the graphics parameters and it does, at least, invoke the onDraw() callback.  Perhaps its a feature (restriction) of the AlertDialog that does not allow invalidation of regions?

Comment: well as i've already written , it all depends which view you are using, since invalidate and onDraw can be implemented in a different way for each . updated my code to show you an example of how to use.

Comment: That is what I did (basically) except the invalidate is done by the reception of data and not a user and thus not in the onCreate(). However, regardless of what values I set in the invalidate(Rect()) function, the canvas.getClipbounds() in the onDraw method always returns the size of the AlertDialog box. (The values obtained by getHeight() and getWidth()). It must be the AlertDialog preventing it. I can't even get it to resize upon orientation shift!

Comment: can you please try out my code inside your alert dialog ? this will be the ultimate test , as i know that my code works fine. this way you will be able to know for sure if that's the cause to your problems. also , if a dialog is what causes your problems , you can just use an activity and set its style to be like a dialog , using this for example(inside the manifest) : android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to do that. The AlertDialog comes on top of the main activity and it is not triggered by any user. There is a single call 'onCreateDialog(int dialogId)' in the main activity class which is only called once (on the first 'showDialog(id)'. I tried registering for an onShow() listener but it was never called after the first time. I will put my code snippet in the original message.  I must also admit I don't know what the role of getClipBounds() is or why it would help. I wouldn't mind a setClipBounds()!

Comment: invalidate (Rect) gives the view a chance to only refresh the content in the given rectangle via the onDraw method , and the view can get teh rectangle via getClipBounds . if you didn't know all of this , why did you want to use it anyway?

Comment: I understood the getClipBounds() as a diagnostic. It will tell me what the region to draw is. So that doesn't help me set the region. Since invalidate(Rect) is not working, I needed something else. When I DO look at the output of getClipBounds() in onDraw() it is always the full region regardless of the size of my Rect(). At this point I have given up and accepted that I cannot set a region to invalidate in an AlertDialog. I will need to live with a full dialog update every invalidate.

Comment: Android always invalidates the entire view and the clip bounds is always the full rect. Attempting to change the clip bounds means the other parts of the view you didn't draw disappear. Seems like a poor implementation to me. iOS does this much smarter and more performant.

Comment: @PsychoDad This is wrong. The recommendation is to use the invalidate function with a Rect instance, because it's more efficient : "onDraw() will get called but you won't get the Rect you've provided in
invalidate(Rect). What will happen however is that the rendering
pipeline will only execute the drawing instructions that intersect
with the Rect you've supplied with your invalidate call. When onDraw()
is executed, your drawing calls are only recorded for later use. At
playback time they can be ignored. " . Source:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/wHkKLy6wIVk

Comment: @androiddeveloper I understand all of that. However my real world performance differs in that I get vastly improved performance by splitting up my views into a grid and only invalidating those views where the bitmap has changed. This performs far better than calling invalidate on a single view with a rect.

Comment: @PsychoDad OK. You can also use other solutions, like SurfaceView/TextureView.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Surface view won't work as I need to be able to zoom and pan easily in the image, and I am using Android Canvas functions to draw in real time. I've tried TextureView but performance was even worse than View.

Comment: @PsychoDad This sounds odd. OpenGL is always supposed to be better than another layer of UI (Android framework)... Have you tried to use a simple bitmap and change it for the canvas, instead ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes I tried that. It was slower than a regular View. I agree very odd, but that's what is happening.

Comment: @PsychoDad Can you make a github repo showing each of the things you've tried? Maybe I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have hardware acceleration enabled it looks like it just invalidates the whole view...

ViewGroup:

```
public final void invalidateChild(View child, final Rect dirty) {
    final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;
    if (attachInfo != null && attachInfo.mHardwareAccelerated) {
        // HW accelerated fast path
        onDescendantInvalidated(child, child);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: THis is so old I think I long gave up trying to cycle through points one by one and just do it piecemeal and have not looked at it since!